# Mocha test MongoDB: Uncaught TypeError in multiple test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mocha.js

I have written a test but it constantly yields Uncaught TypeError.
I can run the two tests separately. But when I run two tests together, there is problem.
To reuse connection, I write a file to connect to Mongodb

database.js

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var appDb = null;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/theDB'

exports.connectToServer = function(callback) {
     MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            appDb = db;
            callback();
      });
 };

 exports.getDb = function() {
      if(typeof appDb !== 'undefined') {
             return appDb;
       }
 };
```

I then have two tests in the same directory, /test
But when I test with Mocha by tying mocha, test1 runs well but test2 won't run. 
It says:

```
1) Project test suite 'before all' hook:
   Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

test1.js

```
var appDb = require('./database');
var Q = require('q');
var EnquiryForm = require('../EnquiryForm');
var EnquiryFormReset = require('../EnquiryFormReset');
var should = require('should');

describe('EnquiryForm', function() {
      before(function(done) {
            appDb.connectToServer(done);
      });

      describe('.getValue(key)', function() {
            it('should get Key', function() {
               // test using promise;
            })
       });

       after(function() {
             var reset = new EnquiryFormReset();
             reset.reset();
       });
   });
```

test2.js

```
var appDb = require('../database');
var Q = require('q');
var Project = require('../routes/models/Project');
var Clear = require('./MongoScripts/Clear');
var should = require('should');

describe('Project test suite', function() {

    before('project before', function(done) {
        appDb.connectToServer(done);
    });

    describe('.createProject(project), .getProjectById(id)', function() {
        it('can use the createProject to create and getProjectById to find by id.', function() {
        //   another test
        })
    });

    after('project after', function() {
        var clear = new Clear();
        clear.clear();
    });

});
```

Comment: The last }); in test2.js , why ?

Comment: @Sekai, Sorry, it is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how need right write test like you, but i am write this like this:

test1.js

```
var appDb = require('./database');
var Q = require('q');
var EnquiryForm = require('../EnquiryForm');
var EnquiryFormReset = require('../EnquiryFormReset');
var should = require('should');

require("mocha-as-promised")(); //important

suite('EnquiryForm')

before(function(done) {
    appDb.connectToServer(done);
});

test('should get Key', function() {
   // test using promise;
})

after(function() {
     var reset = new EnquiryFormReset();
     reset.reset();
});
```

test2.js

```
var appDb = require('../database');
var Q = require('q');
var Project = require('../routes/models/Project');
var Clear = require('./MongoScripts/Clear');
var should = require('should');

suite('Project test suite');

before('project before', function(done) {
    appDb.connectToServer(done);
});

test('can use the createProject to create and getProjectById to find by id.', function(done) {
//   another test
})

after('project after', function() {
    var clear = new Clear();
    clear.clear();
});
```

You can try, i hope this help you

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It seems that I have some problems understanding before and after hook.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run your code so can't be sure, but it appears that the problem is with your your require statement in test2.js

```
var appDb = require('../database');
```

You are looking for /database one folder level too high, and so `appDb` in test2.js is being set to `undefined`, which isn't a function, as mocha is telling you when you try to call it in `before()`.